# how to uninstall phpmyadmin, I keep getting "error exit status 127"

Tags: 16.04, apache2, uninstall

I tried to uninstall phpmyadmin with this :

```
sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin
```

but everytime get this error :

```
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 phpmyadmin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I also tried other solutions in internet like :

```
sudo apt-get --force-yes remove phpmyadmin
```

still get the same error.

Thanks for the answers

Update : here is the full output :

```
sudo apt-get purge phpmyadmin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dbconfig-common dbconfig-mysql javascript-common libjs-jquery
  libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore libmcrypt4 php-gd php-mcrypt php-phpseclib
  php-tcpdf php7.0-gd php7.0-mcrypt
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  phpmyadmin*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 25.0 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 218432 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing phpmyadmin (4:4.5.4.1-2ubuntu2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/phpmyadmin.prerm: 88: /etc/dbconfig-common/phpmyadmin.conf: [Servers][][AllowRoot]: not found
dpkg: error processing package phpmyadmin (--purge):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
/var/lib/dpkg/info/phpmyadmin.config: 88: /etc/dbconfig-common/phpmyadmin.conf: [Servers][][AllowRoot]: not found
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 phpmyadmin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Can you please provide the *full* command output instead of just a partial snippet? Also what version is it and from where?

Comment: @ByteCommander 

I am really a beginner in ubuntu, a few months ago I installed it and I don't remember from where. 
I use this command  " apache2 -v " to find out its version but here is the output :

The program 'apache2' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install apache2-bin

Comment: @ByteCommander I updated my question with full output